# Windows 11 crashes (black screen) after enabling the "Virtual Machine Platform" for WSL2

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

My OS is Microsoft Windows 11 Home Single Language, and I've been trying to install WSL following all the required steps:

1. `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart`
2. `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart`
3. `wsl --install Ubuntu`

Whenever I activate the *Virtual Machine Platform* feature, after I restart my PC the screen goes black and stays black for hours (1h:30m).

I tried installing from Microsoft Store directly but the same thing happens.

What do you think can be the problem? I'm really stuck.

Note: SVM is enabled on my BIOS. I have x64 based system

In case any of this is relevant:

- *Processor:* AMD Ryzen 5 3550H with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx, 2100 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
- *System Model:* TUF Gaming FX505DD_TUF505DD
- *System Type:* x64-based PC
- *OS Name:* Microsoft Windows 11 Home Single Language

I followed [this guide](https://www.windowscentral.com/install-windows-subsystem-linux-windows-10) to install WSL

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the question , my BIOS setting are as they should be,svm enabled , whenever i enable the feature:VirtualMachinePlatform and restart my PC goes black

Comment: @John the Hyper-V "feature" itself shouldn't be required for WSL2.  Enabling the "Virtual Machine Platform" feature should bring in "just enough" of Hyper-V for WSL2 to work.  I was just about to suggest, though, that enabling Hyper-V could be used as a troubleshooting step (to see if it still freezes with-Hyper-V but without-virtual-machine-platform.  BUT, that's not going to work either since the OP is using Windows Home -- the Hyper-V feature can't be enabled on Home.  It requires Pro or greater.

Comment: **Hyper-V** is not required for WSL2. Please stop asking if Hyper-V is enabled to questions about WSL. How is the author who has Windows 11 Home Single Language supposed to enable a feature that their edition of Windows 11 **DOES NOT** even support. We should help the author solve their problem not suggest they spend unnecessary money to upgrade to Windows 11 Professional

Comment: @nermineslimane If the answer I've given doesn't work, could you add your Windows *release/build* information to the question?  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - There is a 99% chance it’s Windows 11 21H2. The author already indicates they have Windows 11 Home Single Language installed. I find it highly unlikely an inexperienced Windows user would install a Insider Preview build of Windows 11. However, I would agree that increasing the amount of memory for UMA Frame Buffer is indeed the solution

Comment: @Ramhound Good point.

Comment: [Here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/pa-280) is the AMD article on UMA Frame Buffer

Answer (score 3):

After enabling the features such as `WSL` or `HyperV`, you restart, and if the screen goes black after the restart, you just have to follow a minor fix. Works for me on Asus TUF laptop.

Its a UMA buffer issues that is mostly common on `AMD` CPU

1. Enter the **BIOS** Menu
2. In **Advanced** you may see a **UMA Buffer size** option. Set it to Auto, if Auto is not available just don't set it to **128** , **256**, or **512**.
3. Save the changes and restart.

Now you may see the fix working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Soliciting off-site contacts or sponsorships in your answers is not acceptable. You are free to add a tip jar or etc to your profile page, though. However, the normal way to indicate appreciation here is through upvotes. See also [How not to be a spammer.](/help/promotion)

Comment: This very well worked for my Asus TUF FX505DY. Setting it to Auto resolved the issue!

Comment: FX505DT here, setting UMA to auto fixed it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shot based on a quick Google search for *enable hyper-v black screen* (since it *might* also apply to WSL2's VMP).  The first result is from Lenovo which mentions that a black screen can occur on ThinkPad E495/E595 (which are also AMD-based).  Further, [this Github comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5617#issuecomment-1003512480) indicates that the same problem/solution worked on a TUF for WSL2 specifically.

The solution (or at least workaround) in both cases was to increase the UMA Frame buffer size in the BIOS settings to 1GB (or more, or "auto").  Is that setting available to you on your TUF?

Comment: wsl does not require hyper-v it just requires VirtualMachinePlatform to be enabled i've given in the uestion details of my system, BIOS and Processor (i have windows 11 home standard and x64 system based and amd ryzen 5)

Comment: @nermineslimane I absolutely understand that you don't need to enable the Hyper-V *feature* in order to install WSL2.  However, when you enable the Virtual Machine Platform, that actually *does* enable the Hyper-V Type 1 hypervisor and a subset of Hyper-V functionality.  See [this Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5617) where therealkenc (one of the WSL2 developers) mentions that the problem is probably with Hyper-V even though it occurs after enabling VMP.  Note that all reports in that issue were AMD laptop users.

Comment: @nermineslimane Again, in case you missed it, at the bottom of that Github issue there's a user that solved this problem **with VMP on a ASUS TUF FX505DT** by using the same UMA Frame Buffer changes.  Granted, it consumes a lot more memory ...

Comment: After checking i fund out that the  UMA Frame buffer size on my BIOS is set to auto

Comment: @nermineslimane And how much RAM is on that system? "Auto" may be setting it too low. Did you try the 1GB option per the Lenovo recommendations, or is that going to consume too much?

Comment: I have 16Gb RAM  I set the buffer to 1Gb,This solution didn't work for me :(